# Concavity with integrals?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

When asked to find the interval on which the following curve is concave upward
$$
y = \int_0^x \frac{1}{94+t+t^2} \ dt
$$

What is basically being asked to be done here? Evaluate the integral between $[0,x]$ for some function and then differentiate twice to find the concavity of the resulting function?

Comment: Do you know that $y''\leq 0$ tells a lot about convexity? Are you able to prove that $y''\leq 0$ through the fundamental theorem of Calculus? Hint: you do not need to compute the integral in a explicit way.

Comment: Hint: $y = y(x)$. How do we see if a function $y$ is concave up?

Comment: Set the second derivative equal to zero?

Comment: Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.  It is "fundamental," you should know it.

Comment: a function is concave if $f(\frac{x+x'}2)\geq f(x)/2+f(x')/2$. 
Now use the lineartiy of the integral operator

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

$$y'=\frac1{x^2+x+94}\;,\;\;y''=-\frac{2x+1}{(x^2+x+94)^2}$$

and if $\;x>0\;$ , then the sign of $\;y'' \;$ is...

Comment: Actually you should have said if $x>-\frac12$

Comment: @MarkFischler That's for the OP to deduce. I just observed that the given integral is $\;\int_0^x\;$ and thus assumed it is likely that $\;x>0\;$ ...